# change one select , others selects are changes

Tags: angular, angular-ngmodel

I have a problem with my application. I have to write several selects by using
ngValue  ngModel .
The problem is, when one is changed, others selects are changes to the same value - why?.

### HTML:

```
<select placeholder="Contrat" name="contrat"  [(ngModel)]="contrat" class="form-control">

      <option [ngValue]="contrat" *ngFor="let contrat of contrats"> {{contrat.id}}</option>
    </select>

    <select placeholder="Contrat" name="contrat"  [(ngModel)]="contrat" class="form-control">

      <option [ngValue]="contrat" *ngFor="let contrat of contrats"> {{contrat.id}}</option>
    </select>

    <select placeholder="Contrat" name="contrat"  [(ngModel)]="contrat" class="form-control">

      <option [ngValue]="contrat" *ngFor="let contrat of contrats"> {{contrat.id}}</option>
    </select>
```

What's the solution?

Thanks a lot.

Answer (score 3):

This happens because you are binding the same variable to every select in your [(ngModel)]

You are using two way binds so any change in one select will change the variable. Angular will detect this and update the other binds as well.

Answer (score 0):

In your case you are having the same `[(ngModel)]` for all the three select boxes so when you choose one value from the select box it reflects the other one.

So you have to use different `ngModel` for the three select tags

Comment: Thanks so I should use ngmodel array ?